# Calculating correlations between every item in a list

Tags: python, correlation

I'm trying to calculate the Pearson correlation correlation between every item in my list. I'm trying to get the correlations between data[0] and data[1], data[0] and data[2], and data[1] and data[2].

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats

data = [[1, 2, 4], [9, 5, 1], [8, 3, 3]]

def pearson(x, y):
    series1 = data[x]
    series2 = data[y]
    if x != y:
        return scipy.stats.pearsonr(series1, series2)

h = [pearson(x,y) for x,y in range(0, len(data))]
```

This returns the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` on `h`. Could someone please explain the error here? Thanks.

Comment: The specific error comes from trying to assign `x, y` to an element of `range(0, len(data))`- each element of `range` is only a single integer, so you can't split it up and assign it to two variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) will return you a list of int values while you are trying to use it like it returning you a tuple. Try [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) instead:

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
from itertools import combinations

data = [[1, 2, 4], [9, 5, 1], [8, 3, 3]]

def pearson(x, y):
    series1 = data[x]
    series2 = data[y]
    if x != y:
        return scipy.stats.pearsonr(series1, series2)

h = [pearson(x,y) for x,y in combinations(len(data), 2)]
```

Or as @Marius suggested:

```
h = [stats.pearsonr(data[x], data[y]) for x,y in combinations(len(data), 2)]
```

Comment: Trying to run `h` gives me this error:                             `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in pearson
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`

Comment: You should be able to skip your self-defined `pearson` function and just do `h = [scipy.stats.pearsonr(*comb) for comb in combinations(data, 2)]`

Comment: One more quick question - Is it possible to find out which items in data produced which correlation coefficients?

Comment: What do you mean? Give me a sample output

Comment: Um, so running Marius's code gives `[(-0.98198050606196574, 0.12103771832367667), (-0.75592894601845462, 0.45437105165701003), (0.86602540378443871, 0.33333333333333331)]`. Would it be possible to find out which two items of `data` produced a given result?

Comment: You mean this? [((x,y), (data[x], data[y]), stats.pearsonr(data[x], data[y])) for x,y in combinations(len(data), 2)]

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `numpy.corrcoef`

```
import numpy as np
data = [[1, 2, 4], [9, 5, 1], [8, 3, 3]]
```

Result:

```
>>> np.corrcoef(data)
array([[ 1.        , -0.98198051, -0.75592895],
       [-0.98198051,  1.        ,  0.8660254 ],
       [-0.75592895,  0.8660254 ,  1.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The range() function will give you only an int for each iteration, and you can't assign an int to a pair of values.

If you want to go through every possible pair of possibilities of ints in that range you could try

```
import itertools

h = [pearson(x,y) for x,y in itertools.product(range(len(data)), repeat=2)]
```

That will combine all the possibilities in the given range in a tuple of 2 elements

Remember that, using that function you defined, when x==y you will have None values. To fix that you could use:

```
import itertools

h = [pearson(x,y) for x,y in itertools.permutations(range(len(data)), 2)]
```